# Checking for Null Statements in SQLite3

Tags: sqlite, null, statements

Does anyone know how to check if a statement has been prepared or not?  I have searched through the SQLite documentation for statements and searched SO, DreamInCode, and DaniWeb but have found no references to my exact question.

I have a statement that I only call in specific circumstances and I only want to attempt to finalize it if it has been used since program crashes are happening by trying to finalize a statement that has not been used.  I would rather use whatever SQLite has built-in instead of extra code but I will do just that if there is no null-checking for statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/finalize.html) says:

> Invoking sqlite3_finalize() on a NULL pointer is a harmless no-op.

So just ensure that your `sqlite3_stmt*` variables are initialized with NULL, and are reset to NULL when finalized.

Comment: That is what I thought as well but if statement2 is Null my if check on sqlite3_finalize(), if (sqlite3_finalize(statement2) != SQLITE_OK) causes an access violation error.

Comment: Look at the [implementation](http://www.sqlite.org/cgi/src/artifact/ce4e68ea4842cc60); this is not possible. Your pointer must be non-NULL.

Comment: Null as in not initialized.  I have defined it but it is only defined (prepared) under certain conditions.  Anyway I fixed the issue by changing how I executed the code and call finalize from a function before exiting scope of if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(dBase, sqlStr.c_str(), sqlStr.size(), &statement, 0) == SQLITE_OK) instead of when I go to close the dBase connection.